# What are the few things thought to be bad if the Taliban is ruling Afghanistan excluding deprivation of women rights?

Tags: afghanistan, taliban, war-on-drugs

What are the few things thought to be bad if the Taliban is ruling Afghanistan **excluding deprivation of women rights**?

Let's not consider historical aspects. They have agreed to not support any terrorist groups to harm US and its allies. They made similar commitments to other regional countries.

The thing of concern is Poppy. I believe pressure from UNSC can take care of it as everyone wants to take down drugs market. Anything else?

Comment: So you're not interested in women's rights (okay, I can see that it makes sense to include that as it's the obvious answer). But aside from that you're also excluding historical aspects (wouldn't any answer be based on the Taliban's history to predict their future endeavors?), the risk of harboring terrorism, and you already provide an idea about opium production. I'm not sure if that leaves much of a question.

Comment: They don't have a particularly great record with men's rights either.

Comment: You *do* realize your question is, basically, 'what is wrong with the Taliban, other than the things wrong with them?', right?

Comment: @Zibbobz: The question is whether that is actually the case. I basically understand the question as: "Are they pretty much ok, if it weren't for the one big downside about women's rights, or are they flawed in many ways, of which their view on women's rights is just the most striking or well-known one?"

Comment: @Zibbobz If their mistreatment of women is the only negative thing about them, that could be a good answer if you flesh it out.  I'd upvote it.

Comment: @Ryan_L If you rule out mistreatment of its people, historical factors (which is a *wide* swathe to rule out), and drug trade (acknowledged as an issue but still ruled out of any answer) - then what's left?  Other than to say that these things shouldn't be ruled out.

Comment: @Zibbobz Mistreatment of women isn't the only kind of mistreatment possible.  OP is already aware of it, and wants to know what else the Taliban is doing wrong.  Seems like a fair question to me.  A well-cited answer saying there isn't anything else would be just as valuable to me as one that discussed other abuses.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are poppy of such great concern?  The opioid epidemic we have been facing in the last 10-15 years is radically different from past problems with heroin.  We have many, many overdose deaths from fentanyl.  And equivalently many people whose lives have been cut short by pharma opioids such as oxycontin.  Having Afghanistan stop its heroin production would not necessarily influence those *new* facets of the North American drug problems.  Anyways, any cursory search on Talibans pre-2001 will show plenty other wrongs, besides "just" women's rights.

Answer (score 3):

They may keep their word about not letting international terrorists operate from their Emirate. Or they may not.

It's easy to forget these days, but for a long time (practically until 2004) they denied bin Laden had done anything wrong, and by this they meant that there was *any* proof he was involved in attacking the US and refused put him on trial themselves, never mind extraditing him.

There are numerous pre-2000 [cables](https://nsarchive2.gwu.edu/NSAEBB/NSAEBB97/tal40.pdf) on the US engagement with the Taliban. Years before 9/11, bin Laden was sought by the US as the mastermind of the attack on US embassies and on the USS Cole. The Taliban played what can only be called a delaying game. They even offered the US to visit the al-Qaeda training camps, only to delay and then rescind the offer. The Taliban also varied their position on what bin Laden's position with them, often claiming he was under some kind of "restrictions" (without providing details) and at other times bluntly claiming that the "Taliban rules on hospitality" prevent any action against him. They'd accuse the US of having fabricated or coerced evidence against him, etc.

After the fall of Kabul this year, the Taliban have already been [criticized](https://www.voanews.com/south-central-asia/hardline-haqqani-network-put-charge-kabul-security) for appointing the Haqqani network leadership to be in charge of Kabul security, because of the links the network had or has with al-Qaeda and their history of targeting westerners, including journalists:

> “The fact we have Khalil al-Rahman Haqqani in charge of Kabul security is dismaying,” a British intelligence official told VOA on the condition of anonymity. “The Haqqani and al-Qaida have a long history together, you could argue they are intertwined, and it is highly unlikely they will cut ties.”
>
> [...]
>
> The network is also thought by Western intelligence officials to have been behind the 2008 abduction of American David Rohde, a New York Times reporter who managed to escape eight months into his captivity.
>
> The Haqqani Network and al-Qaida ran joint training camps in Pakistan’s North Waziristan region after the U.S. invasion, and according to author Peter Bergen in the book The Battle for Tora Bora, the Haqqani Network helped bin Laden to escape Afghanistan when American forces were closing in on him in 2001.
>
> The network considered forming a joint unit with al-Qaida this year, according to a U.S. Treasury Department report in January, which highlighted the continuing links between the two groups despite the Taliban assurances to U.S. diplomats in Qatar.

Although the article doesn't make this point... one could conceivably say that Haqqani having had such close ties
with al-Qaeda and also (surprisingly) with a [faction of IS-KP](https://blogs.lse.ac.uk/southasia/2020/06/05/long-read-a-complex-tapestry-of-collusion-and-cooperation-afghanistan-and-pakistans-terrorism-networks/) puts them in a favorable position to exert their influence or at least use their knowledge to prevent attacks on the Western personnel still in Kabul... Also, there are reports that the Taliban have [executed](https://www.theweek.in/news/world/2021/08/19/taliban-executes-is-k-chief-a-year-after-afghan-govt-jailed-him.html) an IS-KP leader which they found in a Kabul prison, after they took it over.

Comment: could always add https://www.hrw.org/news/2001/02/19/afghanistan-taliban-massacres-detailed  Any Google search *taliban abuses* , time limited to *before* 2001 would have brought plenty of examples for the OP to chew on.  Off the top of my head:  music - banned, movies - banned, thievery - amputations.